# C# Sandbox Environment

Tags: c#, sandbox, environment

I am working on a Small sandbox project in Visual Studio. Here is my code:

```
namespace Andromeda.PCTools
{
    public partial class Sandbox : MetroForm
    {
        private AppDomain sandbox;

        public Sandbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Sandbox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Applications|*.exe", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    listBoxItems.Items.Add(ofd.FileName);

                }
            }
        }

        private void removeSelectedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBoxItems.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                while (listBoxItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    listBoxItems.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxItems.SelectedIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
            ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();

            Evidence ev = new Evidence();
            //ev.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Internet));
            PermissionSet internetPS = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(ev);

            setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath);



            //StrongName fullTrustAssembly = typeof(Sandboxer).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

            sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain(listBoxItems.SelectedItem.ToString(), ev, setup, ps);

            try
            {
                sandbox.ExecuteAssembly(listBoxItems.SelectedItem.ToString());
                btnLoad.Enabled = false;
                btnUnload.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred!\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void btnUnload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(sandbox);
                btnLoad.Enabled = true;
                btnUnload.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred!\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

But i get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in Andromeda
>   4.0.exe ("Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.")

Comment: Get the error *where*?  There's a lot of irrelevant code up there, see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The assembly you try to execute, does it involve file I/O? If so then wouldn't that actually be expected to happen?

Comment: I basically just want to make an EXE run in an environment where it cant make changes (harm) the device

Comment: Sorta like sandboxie

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the sandbox assembly permission to execute, but you also need to add a [`FileIOPermission`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission(v=vs.110).aspx) to the permissions set, thus giving it permission to access the filesystem.  Try the following:

```
ps.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

Choose how you want to configure your IO permissions appropriately.  In my example its unrestricted, but this is a sandbox.  You may opt to lock it down a little bit :)  Choose the appropriate constructor as needed.

Comment: You can answer your question with the solution you found, and then accept your answer after some time limit has expired.